Is it legal (US) to target drunk people and interview them to create (commercial) content a.k.a. street interviews?
In some forms of street interviews, people seem to specifically target intoxicated pedestrians, some seemingly exclusively young women, put camera and microphone in their face and try to get them answer very intimate question about their sexual life.
On the one hand, interviewing people in the street is a long established practice of journalism and there seems to be nothing special about the format of creating entertainment-journalism by people who run their own YouTube or other video platforms per se.
On the other hand, it would seem that specifically targeting intoxicated people in order to expose private information that they might later regret sharing with the general public (audience), forever stamped into the collective memory of the Internet, a ramification not typically understood by those intoxicated, may go against the idea of proper consent or how a legally binding contract should come to exist. I can see how under certain conditions (evolving events, questions of a "regular" nature) an interview given, even when intoxicated, could be viable, but targeting intoxicated people as a business practice seems to be wrong.
So is it legal, illegal, not yet decided or does it depend on the state?

Just to be clear, are these people choosing to be publicly intoxicated (which is against the law in most jurisdictions) or being forced to be intoxicated in public?

@EndAntisemiticHate For someone being publicly intoxicated to be against the law somebody has to be pretty far gone indeed, not just, for example, too drunk to drive.

@EndAntisemiticHate From what I have seen, it would seem that they're drinking in some club or bar and then go to another club in the same area. I'd say nobody forces them to drink.

The question presents the situation as if it were common.  Maybe it is, and maybe I'm just too sheltered, but although I can totally believe that such things have happened, I wouldn't have thought that it was a whole recognizable thing.

As a note to those unaware: Not all questions are about one's "sexual life", but also generally other questions that will get answers that will get clicks, such as controversial political topics, even going as far as being unreasonable and involving "false dichotomy" (one example here: "LGBT rights or economic stability", which the interviewee expertly answered "both").

@JohnBollinger I read 'sheltered' as 'shattered'. I like that better. Anyway I was not aware it was a thing either though I, like you, am very sheltered (as you put it). I rarely go out - only when i have to. Even so it's quite an interesting question though it does not affect me at all.

I don't have an answer but: it does seem to me that whether it's legal or not it is rather wrong depending on what is asked. It is taking advantage of them. Now they might have put themselves in the position but that does not mean they should be abused like that (and that's what it is). The next step here would be to assault them - and if women we know what that means (not that that has never happened to men). Also what if someone spiked their drink or they felt intimidated to drink (peer pressure etc.)? What if this or that? There are a lot of variables and it's wrong to abuse anyone ever.

.. but of course law often doesn't care about what is morally or ethically wrong. In short whether this is legally allowed or not if it is done it seems really messed up. I would have thought you would have to have consent: though if they were pissed such consent would not be in their right mind anyway so is not really consent.


Is it legal (US) to target drunk people and interview them to create
(commercial) content a.k.a. street interviews?

Basically yes, this is legal.
In some jurisdictions (California has the strongest right of publicity, most other states are weaker, some states have none), there is a right of publicity for commercial use of someone as a model or image, but generally satire or parody or journalism, which is what this is likely to be, is not subject to this limitation.
That fact that someone is drunk is irrelevant. The fact that someone looks stupid and is embarrassed by what they say is irrelevant.

On the other hand, it would seem that specifically targeting
intoxicated people in order to expose private information that they
might later regret sharing with the general public (audience), forever
stamped into the collective memory of the internet, a ramification not
typically understood by those intoxicated, may go against the idea of
proper consent or how a legally binding contract should come to exist.

Absolutely not. And, responding to a street interview doesn't create a contract and doesn't require consent (except to the extent that payment of a right of publicity amount is required).
There is no right to be protected from saying things you regret in U.S. law and with the possible exception of California, which I haven't researched on this point, there is no right to be forgotten. A European style right to be forgotten would probably be unconstitutional under the First Amendment in any case.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Is there no "right of image"? in the US? In Europe if someone interviews you they will make you sign a paper declaring that you agree to let them use the images. Not an actual contract, more like a waiver. I'm pretty sure making drunk people sign a paper like that wouldn't work.

@Stef street interviewers exist in Europe too (thankfully less of them tho) and they generally don't care about getting waivers as far I can tell.

@Stef There is not a true "right of image". Some states have a common law or statutory right of publicity (which can be expressly waived). But this is basically an unjust enrichment claim for the fair market value of hiring that person as a model and only applies to commercial use of the image as a non-incidental use (like as a character in a video game or a model used in branding). It doesn't apply at all to non-commercial use and doesn't afford the person whose image is used control over the use of that image. The details vary materially from state to state.

Couldn't this fall afoul of "revenge porn" statutes if the interviews are of sexually explicit topics?

@nick012000 No. Those statutes cover explicit images not mere words.

The basic principle in the US is that anything which happens in a public space may be photographed, filmed, or recorded.
However, you cannot publish someone's clearly recognizable likeness without a model release except for background of crowd scenes and other cases where their specific presence is clearly incidental rather than the focus of the recording. There are a few other fair use cases, such as news reporting, but as a very rough guideline you can think of it as having copyright over your own likeness subject to those fair use rules.
Note that the issue is publishing / distributing. Taking the recording is allowed; playing it back for anyone who was not present at the time is not, again subject to fair use.
One of the best photos I've taken can probably never be published, because the young lady is essential to the composition, I didn't get a model release from her parents, and though she has been an adult for a long time now and could sign on her own behalf, I have no idea where to find her and ask. I can post an enlargement of the photo on my own wall. If I'm being honest, I can't post it on the web, or let others do so.
So yes, in the US you can be filmed drunk the moment you step off private property. But there are limits on what people can do with the film without being liable to civil lawsuit.
(I've dabbled in both the visual and audible arts; I've had reason to investigate. But, standard disclaimer, I am not a lawyer.)
Addendum: Note that public figures, such as politicians and performers, have a lower expectation of privacy under US law. I do not know the details, but beware of assuming that because an embarrassing photo of a presidential candidate can be safely published the same photo of someone else could be.
There are undoubtedly other edge cases; I believe minors may have an increased expectation of privacy. But I am not a lawyer, and if I was, I would probably be charging anyone who wanted more specific advice. This is, as I said, my best understanding of the best practices for a professional, based primarily on articles on this topic published in photographers magazines and discussion with recording engineers. I may be out of date, and may be misremembering. If it really matters, get professional advice.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Couldn't this fall afoul of "revenge porn" statutes if they're interviewed about sexually-explicit subjects?

@keshlam The question was "is this legal", so statutes like revenge porn statutes that might make it illegal would be relevant to the question.

Granted, I guess.

aren't you missing the "for commercial purposes" bit here... a photograph you take of someone in public does not fall under fair use/copyright laws.  It's only if you would be selling that image that it matters at all if the person is the central subject.  You can distribute it far and wide for free, no?

No. Commercial purposes is not necessary for a use to be a violation. Selling it is not necessary; simply sharing it with someone not present when the photograph was taken can be challenged if someone wants to make a stink about it. Publishing it, even if for free, is a clear violation. Again, the analogy with copyright is a fairly good guide; there are specific exceptions to the rule, but other than those the rule holds. If you think you are going to want to publish, make the effort to get model releases or make sure that your photos cannot be argued to have individuals as their focus.

the "if someone wants to make a stink about it" is the key there.  Laws vary state by state, but in general if it's embarrassing by nature, they might file some sort of civil suit.  So for the OP, someone being drunk would surely fall under that "right to privacy" even though they're in public, and any release they sign while intoxicated would probably be invalid.  It'd probably require a lawyer who specialized in that state's privacy laws to determine all the intricacies there, but it sounds like normal citizens have more right to privacy than celebs.

austria
In Austria, it is illegal to publicly distribute images of people if doing so would violate their "legitimate interests". (§ 78 Abs. 1 Urheberrechtsgesetz)
So, yes, you can interview them, but if they do or say something embarrassing, publishing it without their permission can get you in legal trouble.

To what extent would choosing to answer questions on camera be considered permission? Does it need to be separate permission obtained at a separate time?

@JackAidley an interview subject responding to questions on camera is probably implicit consent only to the recording.  It would likely also constitute consent to broadcast of the recording if there is something that obviously identifies the purpose as one related to broadcasting, such as a sign saying "TV News" on the camera or microphone, or a statement by the interviewer, etc.  In general, consent for making the recording and consent for specific use of the recording are separate matters.

@Jack Aidley: And let's not forget that the person is drunk: Being drunk limits your capacity to contract. Thus, depending on the degree of intoxication, the (implied or babbled) permission might be void anyways.

An interesting question is, if your answer is edited in a way that makes you sound worse than you are (changing order of what you said, and cutting off the nuances you present), does that invalidate the permission you gave them if it didn't allow for such editorializing?

france
In France, it is illegal (except specific circumstances)
Article 226-1 of the French penal code:

Est puni d'un an d'emprisonnement et de 45 000 euros d'amende le fait, au moyen d'un procédé quelconque, volontairement de porter atteinte à l'intimité de la vie privée d'autrui :
1° En captant, enregistrant ou transmettant, sans le consentement de leur auteur, des paroles prononcées à titre privé ou confidentiel ;
2° En fixant, enregistrant ou transmettant, sans le consentement de celle-ci, l'image d'une personne se trouvant dans un lieu privé.
3° (...)
Lorsque les actes mentionnés aux 1° et 2° du présent article ont été accomplis au vu et au su des intéressés sans qu'ils s'y soient opposés, alors qu'ils étaient en mesure de le faire, le consentement de ceux-ci est présumé.


Impunging on another’s privacy is punished by up to one year of jail time and €45000 fine, when one, by any procedure:
1° records or transmits words spoken under an assumption of privacy or confidentiality, without the consent of the speaker;
2° records or transmits the image of a person located in a private place, without the consent of that person;
3° (...)
When acts mentioned in 1° or 2° have been made in view of the targets, and they did not object while being able to do so, their consent is assumed.

Intoxicated persons lack the clarity of mind to object to potentially-embarrassing recordings, so their consent cannot be presumed. The main difficulty for the prosecution is to prove that the words were "spoken under an assumption of privacy or confidentiality". The translation may be a bit questionable but the original, à titre privé, does not necessarily means the information is secret or embarrassing, just that it is not destined to be shared widely (e.g. a wife telling her husband to buy milk on the way home qualifies). It is fairly obvious that the video has value specifically because it features people saying things they usually do not say out loud in public, and they do so because they are drunk and do not completely understand the context (of being filmed etc.).
Of course, if one of the interviewees regularly makes comments about her sex life on public platforms (social media, blog, etc.), under her real name, the defense may credibly argue that this specific person did not speak under an assumption of privacy. But that would be a factual determination specific to that person.
